# Oracle 11g creating table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

hi i'm using oracle 11g to create a table with Object-Relational Features but its not creating the table for some reason

here what i have

```
create type Name as object (
  firstname varchar2(20),
  surname varchar2(20))
  final
create type Address as object (
  street varchar2(20),
  city varchar2(20),
  postal_code varchar2(8))
  not final
```

and for the table

```
create table people (
  (pname Name,
  paddress Address,
  dateOfBirth date);
```

yet its not creating the table, i know its probably something simple and straight forward but i just cant seam to get it to create the table, if somebody could point me in the right direction to get it to create the table that would be great

also when i try create the table i get the following error

```
 ORA-00904: "%s: invalid identifier"
 *Cause:
 *Action:
 Vendor code 904Error at line:2 colimn:2
```

Comment: It works fine, take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f661

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the question is explicitly about Oracle.

Comment: You have an extra paren before `pname` in the `create table` statement.

Comment: As Gordon points out, it's a typo

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TYPE Name as object (firstname varchar2(20), surname varchar2(20)) FINAL;

CREATE TYPE Address as object (street varchar2(20), city varchar2(20), postal_code varchar2(8)) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TABLE people (pname Name, paddress Address, dateOfBirth date);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9832f1)**

Comment: that's seams to work, however i cant see any table on the side panel like it usually does when creating a normal table, thanks

Comment: @Michael It creates the table :) To view the schema, create on `Browser` button :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
create type Name as object (
firstname varchar2(20),
surname varchar2(20))
final );


create type Address as object (
street varchar2(20),
city varchar2(20),
postal_code varchar2(8))
not final);
```